# Remove lines between patterns nearest another pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to remove certain objects from a PDF file. The objects all look like this:

```
40 0 obj 
<<
/PieceInfo 
/Subtype /Form
/Resources 
<<
/Font 
<<
/Fm1 35 0 R
>>
>>
/Type /XObject
/BBox [0 -22.5 131.05 0]
/Length 601
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]
>>
stream
  . . .
  A bunch of compressed gibberish here
  . . .
endstream 
endobj
```

What I found to work without breaking the PDF document is deleting the stuff between `obj`, `stream`, and `endstream`.

Is there a way in `sed` or `awk` to look for lines containing `/Form`, and then deleting everything between the nearest `obj` above and `stream` below, and that `stream` and the `endstream` below it, so that the final result looks like this:

```
40 0 obj 
stream
endstream 
endobj
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$pdf"
40 0 obj 
<<
/PieceInfo 
/Subtype /Form
/Resources 
<<
/Font 
<<
/Fm1 35 0 R
>>
>>
/Type /XObject
/BBox [0 -22.5 131.05 0]
/Length 601
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]
>>
stream
  . . .
  A bunch of compressed gibberish here
  . . .
endstream 
endobj
```

You can use `perl`:

```
$ echo "$pdf" | perl -0777 -lne 'print "$1$2$3\n" if /(^.*(?<=\bobj)\s*\R)[\s\S]*?\/Form[\s\S]*?^(stream\s*^)[\s\S]*?^(endstream\s+endobj)/m'
40 0 obj 
stream
endstream 
endobj
```

[Demo and explanation of regex](https://regex101.com/r/53Lfgy/2/)

Comment: I get nothing in the output. Maybe it's a perl version issue? I've got `v5.22.1`.

Comment: @SU3 - No.  This works for me under the same version.  It's likely to do with special characters in the PDF that didn't translate onto your posted input on SO.

Comment: Actually, I checked against that by using the text you posted as input.

Comment: @SU3 - I didn't post it :)  I am noticing however this deletes all lines that don't fall into your specific delete pattern.  (`echo "hello\n" | perl -0777 -lne 'print "$1$2$3\n" if /(^.*(?<=\bobj)\s*\R)[\s\S]*?\/Form[\s\S]*?^(stream\s*^)[\s\S]*?^(endstream\s+endobj)/m'` prints nothing)

Comment: Well `echo "hello\n" | ...` would just be no match, so nothing printed. I would tell you to experiment with the link on Regex101 and make changes as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<=obj)[\s\S]+?\/Form[\s\S]+?\n(?=endstream)/\nstream\n/g' pdf
```

There are a LOT of ways this regex can backfire (The key issue is "obj" or "endstream" appearing midstream or those fields or "/Form" being missing).  You'll need a full script for something production quality, in which case you would definitely need to "show your work" to get help.  Also you may need to remove or change the `\n` before `(?=endstream)` for an actual PDF.  I'm not familiar with the line end characters it uses.

The jist, as a glob, would be that it looks for `obj*/Form*endstream`, and then clobbers everything not in a lookaround `(?[etc])`, and it manually readds the `stream` line.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` may also do the job,

```
awk '/[^end]obj/||/[end]*stream/{print;if(d==1){s=""}d=1;next}{s=s $0}END{print s}' pdf
```

Brief explanation,

1. `/[^end]obj/||/[end]*stream/`: locate the string 'obj', 'stream', and 'endstream'
2. If above string is existed in the line, print it and enable the flag `d`
3. If the `d` is already enabled, clear the buffer `str`
4. Print the `str` in the end

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\<obj\>/{n;:a;/\<endobj\>/!{N;ba};s/.*\<(stream)\>.*\<(endobj)\>/\1\n\2/}' file
```

Gather up the lines between `obj` and `endobj` and remove the parts either side of `stream`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$NF == "endobj" {
    print (obj ~ "/Form" ? "stream" ORS "endstream" : obj)
    obj = ""
    inObj = 0
}
inObj  { obj = (obj == "" ? "" : obj ORS) $0 }
!inObj { print }
$NF == "obj" { inObj = 1 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
40 0 obj
stream
endstream
endobj
```